# Blacklisted careers tags still show up in search results

Tags: feature-request, jobs

People really shouldn't blacklist too many things, so as not to close career avenues.  But if I've listed [java](/questions/tagged/java) under "dislikes", beside the field it reads:

[image]

So why do [java](/questions/tagged/java) jobs still show up in my search results then?  Shouldn't any jobs listing [java](/questions/tagged/java) then be stripped out, since I blacklisted it?

Comment: Not every job tagged `java` may have such an enormous amount of Java in it that it's a dealbreaker for you... The second suggestion is cool but would be better off in a separate question?

Comment: Yes, thought I'd break the 2nd into a separate,

Comment: @Pëkka I think this question gets at, if you've listed _Java_ as a dealbreaker, and the job lists Java as a requirement, then the site should account for that.  What would the hiring manager do seeing _Java_ in your dislikes and _Java_ in the job description?

Comment: Still, "meh" to automated filtering. What if I toyed with the "dislikes" field a year ago and forgot it? What if my preferences have changed? Your other suggestion I support though

Comment: I also thought so.  Perhaps "dislikes" should actually be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The truth is, we have two products, the CV search product where employers pay us to search through all listed CVs, and the job board where employers pay to list available jobs.  Currently there is *no* overlap between these products.  Although we have a lot of ideas for using more information from your CV to help you find jobs, changing the job search product is not our top priority yet.  Before that we are working to improve our ad serving algorithm and developing an improved job matching tool which will affect both candidate search from the employer side and some non job list tools from the candidate side.

As for the "dealbreakers" verbage, Pëkka is right, job tagging is not an exact science and often times language tags show up on jobs that shouldn't.  Additionally, tags are not required, so the java tag may well be missing on a listing that is exactly a java developer.  And then there is the case where you would love to actual challenge of the work (something like solving world hunger via programming, of course replace that with whatever you'd love to do), but would you really turn it down just because you'd have to work in java?  I'm not really in favor outright removing listings for this reason.